# Error Establishing a Database Connection - Using Postgres / pg4wp

Tags: wordpress, postgresql

I've solved this problem when faced with a MySQL setup, but I seem to be falling short when we use PG.

Issue: **Error establishing a database connection**

Here's my wp-config.php:

```
// ** Heroku Postgres settings - from Heroku Environment ** //
$db = parse_url($_ENV["DATABASE_URL"]);
if($_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]==="localhost") {
define('DB_NAME','finpipe_dev_db');
/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER','ilia');
/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD','ilia');
/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST','localhost');
} else {
// ** Heroku Postgres settings - from Heroku Environment ** //
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME',trim($db["path"],"/"));
/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER',$db["user"]);
/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD',$db["pass"]);
/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST',$db["host"]);
}
/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET','utf8');
/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE','');
```

Here's my output from being inside the Postgres console:

```
    List of databases
        Name        |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
--------------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+----------------------- 
 finpipe_dev_db     | ilia     | UTF8     | en_CA.UTF-8 | en_CA.UTF-8 |
```

I've even done `ALTER USER ilia WITH PASSWORD 'ilia';`

And yet, still getting hit with **Error Establishing**...

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

This error you are getting is probably because PostgreSQL isn't accepting connections. Please check pg_hba.conf and postgresql.conf files in your PostgreSQL instance directory, you might have to configure them in order to be able to access your database.

Try to configure the following and test, if it works, you'll need to find the correct configuration (this one allows all)

pg_hba.conf

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

postgresql.conf

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```